# Customizing error messages for symfony valid constraint with collection type

Tags: php, validation, symfony-forms, symfony-2.8

I have a symfony form with `Collection Type`

Parent Form

```
->add('items',
    CollectionType::class,
    array('entry_type'=>PurchaseOrderRawMaterialType::class,
        'allow_add'=>true,
        'constraints'=>array(new Valid()),
        'entry_options'=>array('type'=>$options['type'])
        'error_bubbling'=>false,
        )
   );
```

Child Form

```
$form
    ->add('rawMaterial',
           EntityType::class,
           array('class'=>RawMaterialInventory::class,
                 'constraints'=>array(new NotBlank()),
              )
        )
    ->add('qty',
          NumberType::class,
          array('constraints'=>
                    array(new NotBlank(),
                          new Type(array('type'=>'numeric')),
                          new GreaterThan(0),
                          new Range(array('min'=>0,'max'=>4000000000.9999)),
                          new Regex(array('pattern'=>'/^[0-9]*+(.{0,1}[0-9]{0,4})$/', 'message'=>'Your number must not contain more than four decimal points'))
                    )
               )
          )
    ->add('price',
           NumberType::class,
           array('constraints'=>
                     array(new NotBlank(),
                           new Type(array('type'=>'numeric')),
                           new GreaterThan(0),
                           new Range(array('min'=>0,'max'=>4000000000.99)),
                           new Regex(array('pattern'=>'/^[0-9]*+(.{0,1}[0-9]{0,2})$/', 'message'=>'Your number must not contain more than two decimal points'))
                    )
                )
            );
```

I have no issue whatsoever with this code except for one tiny little detail. I can't find a way to customize the validation error messages given by `Valid()` constraint under `items` form field. All the other validation errors for both child and parent forms are shown correctly with corresponding form field and am able to do whatever I wish to those.

> One other thing I've noticed is that `Valid()` constraint returns the validation error `This collection should contain 1 element or more.`  when the form is submitted with no `items`. As far as I know that validation error belongs to `Count()` constraint so how did it appear here without me not using `Count()` constraint ?. If I assume that `Valid()` constraint internally executes `Count()` on `CollectionType` form fields, What are the other constraints used by `Valid()` ?. Where can I customize these messages thrown by `Valid()`?.
>
> The solution I am looking for cannot involve using validation constraints inside the Entity classes

Answer (score 0):

You can use YAML validation to customize error messages. You will, however, need to register this file appropriately and then define the constraints within. This can be done within the configuration under validation (see docs)

See the code that I provided for an example to get you started.

```
# src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Author:
    properties:
        price:
            - NotBlank: 
                message: 'Price is mandatory, and so may not be blank'
            - Range:
                min: 0
                max: 4000000000.99
                minMessage: "It does not make any sense to sell a product for a price lower than 0"
                maxMessage: "The price may not be more than {{ limit }}"
```

Reference: http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html